# Android emulator for remote headless Ubuntu server (DigitalOcean)?

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator, digital-ocean

I'm pretty new to Android app development.

I want to set up a system for automated testing of an Android app. I currently have a remote server with Ubuntu 16.04 (a DigitalOcean droplet with 1 GB RAM). I've also downloaded and set up the Android SDK on there and created an emulator using `android create avd ...`.

It seems that DigitalOcean doesn't support KVM, and I have to disable it with `-qemu -no-kvm` or else a hardware error pops up.

The problem: the emulator seems to start, but according to `adb logcat`, it loads libraries and other software for about half an hour before finally freezing at a random place, which I can only force quit with `Ctrl-\`.

Is this happening simply because emulator startup is very slow? Is there a way to fix this?

Or, are there better alternatives for Android emulators that can be run from the command line on DigitalOcean servers?

Thanks!

---

When I run the emulator:

```
$ emulator -avd Test1 -no-window -qemu -no-kvm
Error: unable to open display 
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 64MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
emulator: WARNING: QEMU2 does not support snapshots - option will be ignored.
Error: unable to open display 
pulseaudio: pa_context_connect() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Connection refused
pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555   # stays on this line for 20 minutes
Quit (core dumped)                       # Ctrl-\ here
```

Tail end of logcat:

```
D/NuPlayerDriver( 1144): start(0xb6250ca0)
I/GenericSource( 1144): start
I/Process ( 1498): Sending signal. PID: 1588 SIG: 3
I/Process ( 1498): Sending signal. PID: 1498 SIG: 3
I/art     ( 1498): Thread[3,tid=1503,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xafc0d400,peer=0x12c02080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
W/art     ( 1498): Suspending all threads took: 76.883ms
D/NuPlayerDriver( 1144): reset(0xb6250ca0)
I/art     ( 1588): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 1588): Thread[3,tid=1591,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xafc0d400,peer=0x12c210e0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
W/art     ( 1588): Suspending all threads took: 60.021ms
I/art     ( 1633): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 1588): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/DownloadManager( 1633): Upgrading downloads database from version 0 to version 109, which will destroy all old data
I/dumpstate( 1800): begin
I/art     ( 1552): Thread[3,tid=1563,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb1505400,peer=0x746a5080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art     ( 1552): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 1588): Thread[3,tid=1591,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xafc0d400,peer=0x12c210e0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art     ( 1613): Thread[3,tid=1618,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xafc0d400,peer=0x12c07080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art     ( 1588): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 1633): Thread[3,tid=1641,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xafc0d400,peer=0x22c12080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art     ( 1739): Thread[3,tid=1749,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xafc0d400,peer=0x22c07080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art     ( 1613): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 1763): Thread[3,tid=1775,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xafc0d400,peer=0x22c06140,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art     ( 1739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 1763): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 1633): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
# Stopped here
```

Comment: I am also having this issue. Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

1 GB RAM is not enough for the emulator to work correctly.
Because system will take 300-400 Mb for virtual device will be not enough free RAM.

It is better to use a droplet with 4 GB RAM minimum (8 GB is much better).

And seems like Digital Ocean supports KVM now.
At least I've checked it via running `emulator -accel-check` command.
This is a result

```
accel:
0
KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
accel
enter code here
```